# version limitation for triggering my app and opening email attachment

Tags: iphone, ios

I have used CFBundleDocumentTypes and ask system to trigger my app when I touch the email attachment file.

It worked on my iPhone, iPad,
but it has no function on ipod (os 3.1.3).
It only display the options 'Save Image' 'Copy' when I touch and hold the email attachment file.
If I select 'Copy' and paste it to app 'Note', it only display cid:********--**-****-************

Does this function have version limitation ?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CFBundleDocumentTypes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101685) is supported in iOS 3.2 and later and all versions of Mac OS X.

**Document Support** section in [What's New in iOS 3.2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS3_2.html) mentions it.